# Use Perl to select data from SQL database and place into Excel

Tags: sql, excel, perl

I am new to Perl so I'm hoping someone can help me with this
I have two Perl scripts

1. Connects to my sql2008 database and selects 2 columns from one table as an array and prints them using foreach.
2. Uses Excel::Writer::XLSX to generate an Excel file with whatever strings I place in specific rows and columns.

I would like to run script #1 and and have it output into an Excel file. I think I should just be able to combine these two scripts above but I keep getting "requires explicit package" errors. (I assume because my variables don't have `my` in front of them).  I must be way off. Looking for help.

Here is my code that doesn't work:

```
use strict;
use DBI;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

# connect to the db
my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:ODBC:dbname', 'dblogin', 'dbpassword');

 my $sth1 = $dbh->selectall_arrayref("
 select col1, col2 from table");

foreach my $ln (@$sth1) 
{ my($col1, $col2) = @$ln; print "$col1  $col2\n";}

my $workbook  = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( 'col1col2test.xlsx' );
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

$worksheet->write( "A1", "$col1" );
$worksheet->write( "A2", "$col2" );
```

Comment: If you indent your code properly, it's easy to see that `$col1` and `$col2` are only defined within the scope of your loop. Also, when working with DBI, the variable name `$sth` is usually reserved for a statement handle, but what you're getting is an arrayref of arrayrefs, so you should probably name it something else.

Answer (score 1):

The [Excel::Writer::XLSX](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX) module provides a convenience method called [`write_col()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX#write_col-row-column-array_ref-format) for such a scenario as this:

> The `write_col()` method can be used to write a 1D or 2D array of data
>   in one go. This is useful for converting the results of a database
>   query into an Excel worksheet. You must pass a reference to the array
>   of data rather than the array itself. The `write()` method is then
>   called for each element of the data.

After connecting to the database and initializing your spreadsheet objects, you can basically reduce the output portion of your code to the following two lines:

```
my $data = $dbh->selectall_arrayref("select col1, col2 from table");
$worksheet->write_col(0, 0, $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the other mentions, I realize your query is only intended to return a single row, but in general if you have multiple rows it's better to iterate the SQL and then generate the output:

```
use strict;
use DBI;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

# connect to the db
my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:ODBC:dbname', 'dblogin', 'dbpassword');
my $sth1 = $dbh->prepare(q{select col1, col2 from table});

$sth1->execute();

my $workbook  = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( 'col1col2test.xlsx' );
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

my $col = 0;

while (my ($col1, $col2) = $sth1->fetchrow_array) {
  $worksheet->write(0, $col, $col1);
  $worksheet->write(1, $col, $col2);

  $col++;   # maybe you really don't want this...  I don't know
}

$sth1->finish;

$workbook->close();
```

As it stands, if your query does return multiple rows, it seems like you will write the same values over and over to the same cells...

Maybe that's what you wanted, but I thought to mention it.

Answer (score -2):

Your problem is in variable scope, specifically here

```
 foreach my $ln (@$sth1) 
{ my($col1, $col2) = @$ln; print "$col1  $col2\n";}
```

You're defining col1 and col2 inside the foreach loop, so their scope is only the loop. Then trying to use them outside, wher they don't exist.

I'd define col1 and col2 up above the foreach, eg

```
my $col1;
my $col2;
foreach my $ln (@$sth1) 
{($col1, $col2) = @$ln; print "$col1  $col2\n";}
```

A

Comment: With this code, only the last row of the result set will get written to the spreadsheet.